# siunitx: per-mode=fraction in displaystyle with tfrac

Tags: siunitx

Is it possible to display a per-mode=fraction unit as a small fraction (\tfrac) in displaystyle math mode? In the following MWE, the first output is what I want in the displaystyle math mode.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{per-mode=fraction}
\begin{document}

$\SI{1}{\metre\per\second}$
$\displaystyle \SI{1}{\metre\per\second}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the `fraction-function` key of `siunitx`. `\tfrac` is provided by `amsmath`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
  per-mode=fraction,
  fraction-function=\tfrac
}
\begin{document}

$\SI{1}{\metre\per\second}$
$\displaystyle \SI{1}{\metre\per\second}$

\end{document}
```

> [image]